# Detected a TLS handshake to an endpoint that does not have TLS enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, tls1.2, kestrel-http-server

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API running in a Linux Docker container orchestrated using Docker compose. When I try to access the Swagger endpoint of the Web API on `HTTPS`, the browser cannot reach the endpoint, and I see the following error in the Web API logs.

> Detected a TLS handshake to an endpoint that does not have TLS enabled

After reading [this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sni-with-tlshandshakecallbackoptions), I "fixed" the issue by adding the following to my configuration. However, I am not sure why this is needed. It seems overkill and has too much complexity to enable HTTPS, so I am wondering if I am missing something.

```cs
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Listen(
        address: IPAddress.Any,
        port: 443,
        configure: listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
            listenOptions.UseHttps(new TlsHandshakeCallbackOptions
            {
                OnConnection = context =>
                {
                    if (string.Equals(context.ClientHelloInfo.ServerName, "localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                        string.Equals(context.ClientHelloInfo.ServerName, "host.docker.internal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        // Different TLS requirements for this host
                        context.AllowDelayedClientCertificateNegotation = true;

                        return new ValueTask<SslServerAuthenticationOptions>(
                            new SslServerAuthenticationOptions
                            {
                                ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2("/root/.aspnet/https/webapi.pfx", "password")
                            });
                    }

                    return new ValueTask<SslServerAuthenticationOptions>(
                        new SslServerAuthenticationOptions
                        {
                            ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2("/root/.aspnet/https/webapi.pfx", "password")
                        });
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to use different certificates based on host name?

Comment: No. I understand SNI is for the case where you're interested in using a different certificate for different endpoints (e.g., ports). Though, for some weird reason, this was the only workaround to get the HTTPS endpoint working.

Comment: You can use the much simpler API and pass in the cert directly. Here are 3 ways to do that  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#specify-https-using-a-custom-certificate